# hash function for boost_unordered, no default possible?

Tags: c++, boost, hash

I have an class which has `list of items` (an instance of a class called `ItemList`).
This `ItemList` class has functions such as:

```
ItemIndexType AddItem(...);
void DoSomething(ItemIndexType index, ...);
```

`ItemIndexType` acts as some kind of "smart iterator", and has the member variables
`myIter (iterator to a multimap in the ItemList)`,
`myList (pointer to the ItemList)`.
And a few more used for house-keeping.
It is smart since, if I would erase an item from the ItemList, all indices which point to the item will get a cleared. (pointing to the end of the map).

It is working as intended right now, and I rather not change it too much anymore. However for the application I need to do something extra: I'm building a "reset" function:

```
void ResetItem(ItemIndexType ind);
```

This function would then "reset" the item `ind` points to to the original value. I don't want to store the orignal value within the item class, so I decided to create a container which would have as key the itemindex and as value the original arguments with which the item was constructured.

Since ordering is not only not needed, it is also impossible, I think boost::unordered is the way to go.
Changing the deque I used to keep track of the indices to the hash table yielded a weird error though:

> X\boost\functional\hash\extensions.hpp(176) : error C2665: 'boost::hash_value' : none of the 16 overloads could convert all the argument types

Where the list is created by:

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<ItemIndexType, ListDataType> ListContType;
```

How to create a hash-function for a custom datatype?

Comment: "Since Boost.Unordered uses boost::hash it also supports some other types, including standard containers. To use any types not supported by these methods you have to extend Boost.Hash to support the type or use your own custom equality predicates and hash functions." -> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/hash/custom.html

Comment: thanks, that helps me identifying the specific key (the iterator stored in `myIter`. However it still doesn't give a conversion from std::*::iterator to one of the build in types!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an equality predicate and a hash function for your key datatype, see [Equality Predicates and Hash Functions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/unordered/hash_equality.html). You can build your hash function by combining the hash functions of simple types with [boost::hash_combine](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html)

Comment: boost::hash_combine()., just calls "hash_value" for each part of the key.. Problem is that 1 (and the only unique) "part" is an abstract type I don't have power over (std::bidirectional_iterator). There is no overloaded function of `boost::hash_value` for iterators!